# Cómo mostrar checkbox checked en atributo data-id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo este HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="barbecue" id="barbecue" value="oui" class="barbecue" />
<input type="checkbox" name="handicap" id="handicap" value="oui" class="handicap" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animaux" id="animaux" value="oui" class="animaux" />

<div id="divfilter"></div>
```

Y este script:

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
checkboxes.on('change', function() {
  $('#divfilter').text(function() {
    return checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
      return this.name;
    }).get()    
    .join(', ') + '.';
  });
});
```

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar todos los checbox checked en **data-namevar**:

```
<button
  data-namevar="QUIERO QUE SE MUESTREN LOS CHECKBOX SELECCIONADOS AQUÍ"
  class="add-to-cart btn_1 gradient medium full-width">Add to cart <i class="icon_bag_alt"></i>
</button>
```

¿Alguna ayuda de cómo debo hacerlo?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Por ejemplo, ¿qué acción debe ocurrir para poner todos los elementos chequeados en `data-namevar`?

Comment: Tengo 3 input checkbox y quiero mostrar los datos de los checkbox seleccionados en data-namevar, pero data-namevar se encuentra dentro de <button data-namevar="AQUÍ QUIERO MOSTRAR LOS CHECBOX CHECKED">. No sé cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con los métodos

> .data()

```
 $( "button" ).data( 'namevar', function() {
    return checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
     
      return this.name;
    }).get()    
      ;
  } );
```

> .attr()

```
 $( "button" ).attr( 'data-namevar', function() {
    return checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
     
      return this.name;
    }).get()    
      ;
  } );
```

Comment: ¡Funciona! Muchas gracias.